# Is it on-topic to ask for help with listening to german audio?

Tags: support, on-topic

Is it on-topic to ask for help with listening to german audio? Not a long audio, of course, but one or two sentences?

I am aware that, in any of the Stack Exchange sites, good questions are those that (among other facts) are useful not only to the asker, but can be helpful to others too. With this in mind, I believe that a random bad-quality audio with someone speaking german is probably not going to be useful to others.

Also, I know that simply asking "transcribe this five-minute-long audio for me please" is completely out of place for any question here.

But, provided that I believe that the question may be useful for others, and the audio is reasonably short and of good quality (and easy to include in the question with a link), would such a question be on-topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions on understanding short audio passages of spoken German (including dialects and regional variants) are on topic.

Such questions were asked before. They usually are well received by the community as long as they meet other, more [general criteria for asking](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/asking).